# Get a filtered Array based on a filter input

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to "filter" and object based on an input:

```
const transactions =
    [ 
      { _id:1, 
        amount:100, 
        tags:[{id: 1, label: A},
             ]
       },
       { _id:2, 
         amount:200, 
         tags:[{id: 1, label: A},
               { id: 2, label: B}]  
       },
       { _id:3, 
         amount:500, 
         tags:[{ id: 2, label: B}
              ]
       }
 ]
```

I tried using map function to get the final result as:

```
const tag = '1'

const transactionsFilter = transactions.map((transaction) => {
            const filterT = transaction.tags.filter(
                (tagFiltered) => tagFiltered._id === tag
            );
            console.log(filterT);
        });
```

But i got "an object [null, null, null]

I want to obtain an object like:

```
   [ 
      { _id:1, 
        amount:100, 
        tags:[{id: 1, label: A},
             ]
       },
       { _id:2, 
         amount:200, 
         tags:[{id: 1, label: A},
               { id: 2, label: B}]  
       },
       
 ]
```

Becouse just the first 2 , has the tag with id:1

How can I do it??

Comment: just make take the number 1, not the string '1'

Comment: console.log(transactions.flatMap(i => i.tags.filter(f => f.id == tag))). also label should be a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `filter()` on the main array and then apply `some()` on the tags array.

```js
const transactions =
    [ 
      { _id:1, 
        amount:100, 
        tags:[{id: 1, label: 'A'},
             ]
       },
       { _id:2, 
         amount:200, 
         tags:[{id: 1, label: 'A'},
               { id: 2, label: 'B'}]  
       },
       { _id:3, 
         amount:500, 
         tags:[{ id: 2, label: 'B'}
              ]
       }
 ]

let tag = 1
const res = transactions.filter(obj => obj.tags.some(tag => tag.id === 1));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in conjunction with your filter:

```js
const tag = 1;
const transactionsFilter = transactions.filter(transaction => 
    transaction.tags.some(tag => tag.id == tag)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to do this testing of the tags, and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check that the item matches:

```js
const matchTagId = (tagId, input) =>
  input.filter (({tags}) => tags .some (({id}) => id == tagId))

const input = [{_id: 1, amount:100, tags: [{id: 1, label: 'A'}]}, { _id: 2, amount: 200, tags:[{id: 1, label: 'A'}, {id: 2, label: 'B'}]}]

console .log (matchTagId (1, input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function currying to create a re-usable filter creator that can be used on any collection, not just `transactions`. Within this curried function, you'd use `Array.prototype.filter`.

```js
const createIdFilter = collection => id => collection.filter(item => item._id === id)

const transactions = [ 
      { _id:1, 
        amount:100, 
        tags:[{id: 1, label: A}]
       },
       { _id:2, 
         amount:200, 
         tags:[{id: 1, label: A},{ id: 2, label: B}]  
       },
       { _id:3, 
         amount:500, 
         tags:[{ id: 2, label: B}]
       }
]

const filterById = createIdFilter(transactions)

filterById(1) // [ { _id: 1, amount: 100, tags: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Since _id is unique, you might want to do this instead of using something map-like:

```js
const createIdGetter = collection => id => {
  const resultsWithId = collection.filter(item => item._id === id)
  return resultsWithId.length ? resultsWithId[0] : null;
} 

const getItemById = createIdGetter(transactions)

getItemById(1) // { _id: 1, amount: 100, tags: [ [Object] ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `null` values because you made deep equal or you compare both of the type and the value of variables.

I recommend using `filter` with `some` array built-in functions.

You can also use this solution:

```
const tag = 1;
const filteredArray = [];
transactions.filter((obj) =>
  obj.tags.filter((value) => value.id === tag && filteredArray.push(value))
);
console.log(filteredArray);
```